# VBA Split() function not working when ":" is the delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, split

I'm trying to use the split() function to loop through a specified range and split all strings when a ":" is encountered, and replace the existing value with the split value.

```
Dim k As Integer
Dim lRow as Long
Dim startZip_col As Long
Dim startZip_str As String
Dim startZip_result() As String
Dim startZip_decomposed As Variant

For k = 2 To lRow
    startZip_str = Cells(k, startZip_col).Value
    startZip_result = Split(startZip_str, ":")
    
    For Each startZip_decomposed In startZip_result
        Cells(k, startZip_col) = startZip_result(1)
    Next

Next k
```

a example of the values i want to split are:

abc:1234
abc:5678
def:3456

tried debug.print to pinpoint where the errors are, but column value is correctly identified, loop looks fine, not sure where went wrong

Comment: Interesting. I tried your code with `startZip_col = 1 `  and `lRow = 3'`and no other change, It gave me the answer as `1234`  for an input of `abc:1234` . Now I am curious as to what went wrong for you. Do tell more.

Answer (score 0):

**Logic:**

1. Where is `lRow`. `startZip_col` inititalized? Define and initialize your variables/Objects correctly.
2. Fully qualify the cells else it may refer to active sheet which may not be the sheet you think it is. For example `ws.Cells(k, startZip_col).Value` where `ws` is the relevant worksheet.
3. Before splitting, check for the existence of `:`

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    Dim ZipCol As Long
    Dim ZipString As String
    Dim ZipResult As Variant

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    '~~> Change this to the releavant column
    ZipCol = 1

    With ws
        '~~> Get the last row in Col A. Change to relevant column
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = 2 To lRow
            ZipString = .Cells(i, ZipCol).Value
            
            '~~> Check if the string contains ":"
            If InStr(1, ZipString, ":") Then
                ZipResult = Split(ZipString, ":")
                '.Cells(1, ZipCol) = ZipResult(1)
                
                '~~> For testing
                For j = LBound(ZipResult) To UBound(ZipResult)
                    Debug.Print ZipResult(j)
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```